# Why move 32-bit register to stack then from stack to xmm register?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, att, micro-optimization

I am compiling with `gcc -m32` on a 64-bit machine.

What is the difference between the following? Note that this is the AT&T syntax.

```
# this
movd  %edx, %xmm0

# and this
movl  %edx, (%esp)
movd  (%esp), %xmm0
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be `movd  %edx, %xmm0`?

Comment: You forgot to enable optimizations? The difference is that the second one leaves a copy on the stack, which may be needed later. Still, a better approach would be to add the stack write to version #1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq you're right. Let me edit the question.

Comment: @lurker oh, sorry. I was assuming that compiling with gcc gives the AT&T syntax by default. I should have made that explicit.

Comment: That was MY bad. What you have is obviously AT&T syntax but I'm so used to thinking Intel, I completely filtered out the clues. I retract my comment... :)

Comment: Update, this is optimized code, but GCC's default tuning used to like to bounce through memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference in machine state is that the 2nd version leaves a copy on the stack<sup>1</sup>.

GCC's default tuning bounces through memory for some reason.  (Recent GCC may have fixed this for some cases).  It's generally worse on most CPUs most of the time, including AMD, although AMD's optimization manual did recommend it.  See GCC bugs [80820](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80820) and [80833](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80833) re: GCC's integer <-> xmm strategies in general.

Using `movd` would cost 1 ALU uop, vs. a store and a load uop, so it's fewer uops for the front-end but *different* uops for the back-end, so depending on surrounding code the store/reload strategy could reduce pressure on a specific execution port.

Latency is better for ALU `movd` than for store/reload on all CPUs, so the only advantage to store/reload is possible throughput.

[Agner Fog says](http://agner.org/optimize) in his microarch pdf for Bulldozer (the CPU with the slowest `movd %edx, %xmm0`):

> The transport delays between the integer unit and the floating
> point/vector unit are much longer in my measurements than specified in
> AMD's Software Optimization Guide. Nevertheless, I cannot confirm that
> it is faster to move data from a general purpose register to a vector
> register through a memory intermediate, as recommended in that guide.

---

Footnote 1: If you really want that, a separate store would usually still be a better choice to accomplish that state.  Same # of uops, and lower latency (esp. on Intel CPUs.  AMD Bulldozer / Steamroller has 10 / 5 cycle latency for `movd (x)mm, r32/r64`.  1 cycle on Intel.)

```
movd %edx, %xmm0         # ALU int -> xmm transfer
movl %edx, (%esp)        # and store a copy if you want it
```